# How to apply impulse on chipmunk body on a specific direction?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, vimpulse

i am using:

```
 cpVect vector1=cpv(angle, 400);

 [body applyForce:vector1 offset:vector1];
```

**but this not working well as needed to put a correct angle using touch screen
below line of code used for getting angle**

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for( UITouch *touch in touches )
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
        float angleRadians = atanf((float)location.y/ (float)location.x-1);
        float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
        float cocosAngle = -1 * angleDegrees;
       angle = angleDegrees + 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use cpBodyApplyImpulse(cpBody *body, cpVect j, cpVect r) for apply impulse on body.

Comment: i am not using cpbody. to apply this...  this is chipmunkBody *body;  we can applyForce or applyImpulse.

Comment: your vector 'vector1' uses the angle as the x parameter... perhaps try cpvrotate(cpv(0,1), cpvforangle(angleRadians))

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you all for your precious time to give on that.
Finally i found the way to achieve impulse on a chipmunk body on a specific direction.
Now i am using below code.

```
 **angle = angle-90;                  //angle from cctouchesMoved function
 float magnitude=shootPower;        // magnitude range between 200 to 1000
 cpVect impulse = cpv((cos(angle) * magnitude) , -(sin(angle) * magnitude));

 [body applyImpulse:impulse offset:cpvzero];**
```

// applyImpulse gives the right way for putting impulse as needed using above sin and cos theta values.

Comment: Here cpvzero is       **cpVect cpvzero = {0.0f,0.0f};**